# What is the proper way to use 'ContentControl.getOoxml' across native and online Word?

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I am currently developing a Word add-in that utilizes [`ContentControl.getOoxml()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/contentcontrol#getooxml) and am running into behavior discrepancies between Online and native environments.  Within Word Online, it only returns the OOXML equivalent of the contents of a content control, whereas in native Word, it returns the OOXML equivalent of the entire content control--contents and all.  In other words, in the former it behaves like `getInnerHTML` and in the latter it behaves like `getOuterHTML`.

In order to illustrate the issue, I created a simple script that operates on a document with two content controls.  It gets the OOXML of the first and then inserts it into the second:

```js
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    return Word.run(function (context) {

        // Load content controls in test document
        var contentControls = context.document.contentControls;
        context.load(contentControls, 'id');

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            // Get ooxml of first content control
            var ooxml = contentControls.items[0].getOoxml();

            return context.sync().then(function () {
                // Insert ooxml from first content control into second content control
                contentControls.items[1].insertOoxml(ooxml.value, 'replace');
                return context.sync();
            });
        });

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
};
```

When running the script in native Word, you will notice that the second content control ends up with a third content control inside, containing the first control's content. In Word Online, it only has the first control's content.

The test document can be easily created by starting with a blank document and inserting two rich text content controls (preferably with text in the first so you can see the changes), or you can use this [test document](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AoSTP7z7S0tYgh4CQv3_5_OdWQo2) I created.

Both scenarios are certainly useful (in fact, I've always thought it would be cool to have either two separate methods, similar to `getInnerHTML` and `getOuterHTML` (or a `getInner` boolean parameter to specify which to retrieve), but not so much when the functionality is based on the environment it is being executed in.

Is there a way to ensure the functionality is consistent across environments or, if not, a recommended alternative?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? It's a pretty interesting problem - as I assume there must be an analogy with regards to setting ooxml too?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not.  I was able to come up with a temporary workaround for my particular use case, but I do not think that having to account for two different results in code based on an indeterminable environment is the optimal solution.

Comment: Could you describe the workaround?